# Efficient use of foreach and if statements

Tags: r, foreach, doparallel

My goal is to take a 14616 x 14616 matrix (mat) of t-test p-values and take the lower triangle values and turn them into a vector (vec).

```
vec = foreach(i=1:14616, .combine='c') %:%
foreach(j=1:14616, .combine='c') %dopar%{
    if(i>j){
        mat[i,j]
    }
}
vec <- as.matrix(vec)
```

I feel like I'm really losing efficiency with this, and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: When asking questions about code, it's always a good idea to include a tag for the specific language you're using.

Comment: Have you compared the performance to lower.tri() ?

Comment: As in mat[lower.tri(mat)]?  This is incredibly faster actually, thank you!  It makes me think I'm really misusing foreach though for how much faster this was..

Comment: According to `microbenchmark` tests, the `foreach` method is around 4 orders of magnitude slower [on my MacBook Air (mid-2013)].

Comment: `vec.sum = foreach(i=1:length(vec), .inorder=FALSE, .combine="+") %dopar%{
     as.integer(vec[i]<=.05)
 }`

My next step, to count those less than some significance level.  I'm sure there might be some way to again do this far more efficiently, but I'd love to learn ways of gaining efficiency with these these loops as I'm trying to learn how to do parallel processing with this.

Comment: @BPipher This [tutorial about parallel foreach](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/) might help you.